# Selecting rows in SQL only where *all* values do not meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

Given a really simple table in MS SQL like this:

```
User ID | Status
----------------
1         False
2         True
2         False
3         False
3         False
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I would select only users that *don't* have any rows with a `Status` assigned to `True`.

The result would return User IDs 1 and 3.

I have a feeling it's requires more than a straight forward `WHERE` selector, and have been experimenting with GROUP BY and COUNT without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause to get the result.  In your `HAVING` you can use a `CASE` expression with an aggregate to filter out any rows that have a `Status = 'True'`:

```
select [user id]
from table1
group by [user id]
having sum(case when status = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) < 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a057d/2)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me with a problem I was having.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select distinct userid  
from yourtable
where userid not in (select userid 
                     from yourtable 
                     where status = 'True')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please try

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (UserID INT,
                  Status VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
('1', 'False'),
('2', 'True'),
('2', 'False'),
('3', 'False'),
('3', 'False')

SELECT DISTINCT UserID,
             Status
FROM @table AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM @table AS t2
            WHERE t1.UserID = t2.UserID
            GROUP BY UserID
            HAVING SUM(CASE
                       WHEN Status = 'True' THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                    END ) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.[user id]
  from table1 t1
  left join table1 t2
    on t2.[user id] = t2.[user id] 
   and t2.[Status] = 'true'
 where t2.[user id] is null 
 group by t1.[user id]


select distinct [user id]
  from table1 
except 
select [user id]
  from table1 
 where [Status] = 'true'
```